# How to get data shown on rails console into my views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and am having trouble showing what I get in my rails console to my views pages.

In my rails console, I will type `c = Course.find(21)`.
Then when I put `c.scores.all` in my console I get all of the scores columns that are associated with the Course model, with the id of 21.

However, I cannot do the same thing in the controller or the views. I tried putting the same information but it does not find the scores that are associated with the courses_id in the course/show page. I know this is really simple but cannot seem to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: Post your controller action and your view code

Answer (score 1):

Without the code of your controller and your view, I can only **guess** the cause of your problem.

The code `c.scores.all` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an array of models.

A relation is lazily loaded, which means it does not query DB until you retrieve data from it (typically by calling `to_a` or `each` on it). This may be the cause of your problem.

Rails console and irb work, by default, in **inspect mode**, which means whenever you enter an expression, Rails console automatically calls `inspect` on the return value of that expression and prints the result. `ActiveRecord::Relation#inspect` internally calls `to_a` thus accesses DB, so you can see your data in Rails console.

Comment: Good explanation. As we are only guessing, since there is no code to look at, scores can possibly be an association. If that is the case, it would be nice for the OP to read about eager loading on activerecord: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations